# C: Terminating the program by pressing a key

Tags: c

In C, I normally use the `getch()` function to wait for a key to be pressed and then end the program, but recently I read that since it's not a standard function, it's bad programming practice to use it.

So instead of the following:

```
int main() {
    dosomething();
    getch(); //wait for the user to see the results and press a key to end
    return 0;
}
```

What should I do to replace the `getch` ?

Comment: I would generally recommend against this use of getch() in the C program, because 1. the key conveys no information whatsoever which is generally considered bad UI design, and 2. it breaks pipeling (which now also works pretty well under Windows, or so I'm told).

Under cmd.exe, consider wrapping your C program in a little .bat with the pause command at the end.

Comment: @digitalarbeiter: If you want to be able to "timeout" in the bat file you can also use the choice command: `choice /c ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 /d y /t 10 /n /m "Press Any Letter or Number Key to Continue"`

Comment: If you want the "anykey" behaviour, then on *nix* you could use ncurses to give the getch() to you, and use the getch. But I +1-ed the digitalarbeiter's comment - I recently had to work with precisely this "press any key" use in someone's program - which I needed to execute in batch mode. Took a couple of hoops to convince the program I was "pressing the button".

Comment: Take a look at my comment on AlexKR's answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getc(stdin);` 
is portable in this sense

Comment: ...but leaves only one key that may be pressed with the same effect as when using getch().

Comment: I think that's what the OP wants.
An efficient way (in case you want to have a lot of user response) would be:     #define GL puts("Press any key to continue..."); getc(stdin); calling GL; from your code.

Comment: BTW it doesn't seem to work in C++, I tried getc(stdin) and it doesn't continue till I press Enter.

Answer (score 4):

Using a non-standard I/O function isn't bad practice *per se*; it becomes an issue if you intend to port this code to a different platform that doesn't support `getch()`.

The problem is, there are *no* standard library functions that detect individual keystrokes (`getchar()` and `fgetc()` are buffered and require you to hit Enter before they return); you're going to have to use something non-standard to do that.  If you only intend for this code to run on this specific platform, use `getch()` if that's what you need and just remember that this solution won't necessarily apply to other platforms.  If you intend to port this code to platforms that don't support `getch()`, isolate the system-specific call behind a wrapper function so that when you port the code, only the code inside the wrapper function needs to change.

```
int getKeystroke(void)
{
  /**
   * Put platform-specific call here
   */
  return getch();
}

int main(void)
{
  ... // do stuff here
  getKeystroke();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could fix the terminal window to not go away.

Comment: @ndim: how do you do that for Windows?

Comment: Last time I looked, there was some setting to that effect in some menu.

Answer (score 1):

`getchar()` is standard but due to line buffering you will still need to press `Enter` before `getchar` returns.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer running program from command line.

Comment: no use if you are running in the debugger as the output disappears. (Personally, I set a breakpoint...)

Comment: With `Code::Blocks`, the terminal window keeps showing after the program has been executed: http://www.codeblocks.org/

Answer (score 1):

I think using getch() is the most common by far is keeping a console window from closing , but in C++ most experienced programmers will recommend that you use cin.get

```
 std::cin.get();
```

instead of:

```
getch();
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Turbo C compiler? `getch()` is widely used there.

OTOH if you want the program to wait, run the binary inside the shell/terminal/prompt. Navigate to that directory and invoke

**Windows:**

```
C:> executable.exe
```

**Linux:**

```
~$ ./exec
```

You can use `getchar()`, the only problem being that it is buffered. `getch()` isnt buffered. You can make `getchar()` also to be non-buffered, but the code for that is not worth it. I tried it once, but due to it's sheer complexity never bothered to try it again.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to other answers, you can also use this in windows, especially if your intention is to wait for key press to finish the program:

```
system("pause");
```

Comment: What's standard in `system("pause");`? Andreas wants to make his program more standard, not more dependent on a specific OS

Comment: I clearly stated that my answer was for Windows. I also said that I bring this option as and addition and what might be good use case for it. The issue with getch is not OS specific, it's compiler specific. Person shouldn't be downvoted for bringing another perspective to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to answer something different, you can use

`while(1) 
    sleep(10);`

at the end of main function (before `return 0;`) and then you can press ctrl-c to terminate the program. I think you should not face portability issue and I hope this is not bad programming practice either :)

Comment: @Andreas Grech what do you think which one is best suited answer to you ?